# EC2 Redhat Cloudera Manager CDH Cluster Installation | Hostname Could Not Be Resolved

Tags: hadoop, amazon-ec2, redhat, cloudera

I am trying to install and run Cloudera on an Amazon EC2 Redhat small size instance.

I Have configured the OS FireWall and my AWS Security Group to allow ports 22, 1780, and ICMP Echo Reply.

I successfully downloaded and installed CDH, Cloudera Manager Installer bin on the Redhat instance and I can successfully log into the Cloudera Manager via `http://ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.compute-1.amazonaws.com:7180`

Now when I get to the screen where I "Specify hosts for your CDH cluster installation" I type in the IP of my EC2 instance (as it shows in Redhat: `[ec2-user@ip-xxx.xxx.x.xxx ~]#` and click to Search on port 22.
Cloudera Manager searches for a while then gives me an error that says "Hostname could not be resolved".

Please any feedback or suggestions. I've been following a couple of tutorials that show these steps. I've tried everything and am stuck. Is this a Redhat problem or something else? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the screen where I "Specify hosts for you CDH cluster installation" in the Cloudera Manager, I tried entering my ec2 instance address, ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.compute-1.amazonaws.com, rather than the Host IP. I can now get past this problem. 
So if you are having similar problems, try that.